# CRM2011 Revise Quote in Offline Mode throws Error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, primary-key, outlook-addin

Hy Guys,

if I want to revise a Quote in Offline mode I got an strange error from the CRM2011 Outlook Client.

It Shows up this message:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Primary Key must be populated for calls to platform on rich client in offline modeDetail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220931</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Primary Key must be populated for calls to platform on rich client in offline mode</Message>
  <Timestamp>2013-11-18T13:26:59.1546088Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Everything still works fine in Online Mode.

Basically I have no idea why this error appears.

We don't have any custom code on revise or something like that. We only make some checks on activate Quote but not in revising.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you make sure all the data you need for the quote is being pulled down in the offline sync?  Including the quote detail record information and everything used there.

Comment: Hy, thanks for the answer. First, all Quote Details should be synced. I can manually add new Quote Details and save it without any issue. I have no Problem with adding, editing and stuff like that with These Quote Details.
Did you know whats so different on Revising a Quote?

Answer (score 0):

We figured out that for some reasons Revising a Quote in Offline Mode is not supported.